# Likelihood in mixture models

Tags: likelihood, gaussian-mixture-distribution, mixture-distribution

As per my understanding, normally, when we talk about Bayes rule, we write:

*p(z|x)* = [*p(x|z)* * *p(z)*] / *p(x)*

where,

- p(z|x) is called posterior
- p(x|z) is called likelihood
- p(z) is called prior
- p(x) is called marginalized likelihood: p(x) = ∑<sub>z</sub> p(z)*p(x|z)

In case of mixture models, for an instance, let's suppose we are performing learning using maximum likelihood estimation, that is, trying to find parameters that best represent the data using maximum likelihood estimation. In that case, we consider marginal likelihood as our likelihood of interest. Reference: [here](https://www.coursera.org/lecture/mixture-models/the-likelihood-function-3PDPB).

I was confused as to why likelihood in mixture model is considered as p(x), the marginal likelihood, and not p(x|z). Could anyone please help me understand the concept here? Thank you!

Comment: You are probably confusing p(x) with marginalization with respect to latent variables. Research latent variable models

Comment: May be somehow related to the above question I asked, but I am really confused regarding: Why do we marginalize latent variables in the likelihood of latent variable models? When showing that MLE cannot be used for latent variable models, likelihood is taken such that latent variables are marginalized. Why is it so? Could you please provide me some info on this? @J.Delaney